# Pot de Crème too thick

Tags: dessert

I needed to increase the serving quantity of Food Wishes Pot de Crème (just cream, sugar and chocolate - no eggs) but I clearly got the ratios wrong and it has set rather too thick. It is edible, but the consistency is much harder than it should be.

With less than 4 hours until my guests arrive and no spare cream to thin it out, what are my options? Plan A is just to leave it out at room temperature and hopefully it will soften up a bit, but I have my sous vide bath currently running, so I could possibly gently reheat it in there then serve it warm. My partner is aghast at this, as they believe chocolate mousse type desserts should be served really cold. Plan C is to melt it down, and thin it out with milk but I risk it becoming grainy and I doubt if it will set in such a short time.

I'm going with plan A unless anyone has a better idea ....

https://foodwishes.blogspot.com/2011/02/valentines-day-chocolate-mocha-pot-de.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be fine to serve it warmer than room temperature, but it will soften significantly as it warms and the texture would likely be fine even below room temperature, as the milkfat will be much softer once it gets a bit above refrigerator temp.

Remember that it’s not a mousse; it’s a ganache. It’s not meant to be light or ethereal. It’s meant to be dense and decadent.

If you do decide to thin it, do so with cream, not milk.

Comment: By the time it warmed up it wasn't too hard, although it was a bit too rich for one guest. As culinary disasters go, it wasn't too bad, certainly in low single figures.

Comment: @Greybeard If it consists only of sugar, cream and chocolate it is supposed to be super rich. Serve in suitably small portions and warn ahead, the expection of your guest was wrong not the dish.